# Minimum vertices set bipartite graph covering-special case

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

I was wondering if anyone here could give me any pointers as to how to solve the following problem.

Let ***B=(L,R,E)*** be an undirected bipartite graph, ***∀u∈L, ∃ s= {ei(u,wi)} ∈E; i=1,2.....n*** connect ***u*** to ***wi***, where ***w∈R***.

The problem is to find a minimum set ***K*** from ***L*** covering all ***R*** in ***B, K⊆L , ∑u∈K*** is minimal.

To clarify what I mean by covering: all vertices of ***R*** should should have at least one edge to any ***u∈K.***

My intuition is that it's NP-Hard. If that is the case, any idea of what would be the best way to approximate the result (ie a minimum set ***K*** of ***L*** covering ***R***)? Such that:

- Each vertex from ***L*** could cover multi-vertices of ***R***
- The vertex from ***L*** which has maximum edges toward ***R*** will be selected first
- Each vertex of ***R*** is connected with at least one vertex of ***L***

Edit: Here is an example, consider the following bipartite graph: ***G={L∪R,E},
L={1,2,3,4,5,6},
R={A,B,C,D} ,
E={1A,1B,2A,2B,2C,3A,3C,4A,4B,4D,5A,5B,6A,6D}***

And here is a covering minimum set will be ***{2,4}***

I have read many algorithms and solutions like maximum matching, complete matching, stable marriage, set cover problem, vertex cover in hypergraphs ...etc.
Unfortunately no one match my case.

So i am here asking your help guys cause i about to fed up!!! SOS!!
[image]

Comment: The greedy algorithm by Ciaccia is not the optimal solution!!! Please see! http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~shuchi/courses/787-F07/scribe-notes/lecture02.pdf

Answer (score 6):

This is just the [set cover problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover) in disguise, to each vertex of $L$ assign the set of vertices of $R$ in its neighborhood. We now have transformed $L$ into a set of subsets of $R$ so now we want to find the set covering with the fewest sets.

It is true, as you suspected that this problem is $NP$ complete, but a lot of research on it exists.

Comment: Thank you very much, after converting L into a set of subsets, and find the set covering, how to identify which vertices of L cause we have set of subsets not vertices. Is this an optimal solution?!!

Answer (score -2):

I recently stumbled upon this problem as well and I thought about it.

I believe your problem to be easily solvable in polynomial time and not being related to the classical NP-complete set vertex cover as @jorge-fernández suggested, since you only care about vertices on one side of the bipartite graph and not on both. This difference makes everything way more simple.

The greedy algorithm is quite trivial:

1. Chose a vertex A from v1 which covers "more" nodes left in v2 (i.e the vertex from v1 with more edges)

   - Add the vertex A the `mininum cover set`
   - Remove all the nodes in v2 having an edge to A
   - Remove the vertex A from v1
2. In case v2 is not empty, go to point 1

The algorithm produces an optimal solution and terminates in polynomial time.

- The optimal solution is returned because picking up the vertex with more edges from v1 does not prevent any remaining vertex from being picked up later on (i.e. taking this step does exclude any other vertices nearby to be selected later in the process. This instead happens in the classic NP-Complete problem). The *descent* is convex and we will not land in a local minumum
- In the worst case, the algorithm will take |v2| loops to complete (every loop will just remove a single vertex from v2)

Comment: This does not work because, for example, it cannot notice or take advantage of cases where a vertex picked early on has been made redundant by vertices picked later. For instance, if you have vertices $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ in $V_2$ and vertices adjacent to $\{1,2,3\}$, $\{1,4\}$, $\{2,5\}$, and $\{3,6\}$ in $V_1$, the greedy algorithm chooses all four vertices when in fact you only need the last three.

Comment: Also, you are missing the point of the reduction to set cover; it also only cares about vertices in $V_2$, since vertices in $V_1$ get transformed into subsets of $V_2$ and we do not have to use all the subsets in the cover.

Comment: Hi @MishaLavrov, thank you for your explanation. My original problem was slightly different, where vertices in V2 had at most 2  edges (either 1 or 2 connected vertices in V1). In my special case the greedy algorithm seems to work fine, but as your example shows in the more general case it fails.

Comment: It seems like my example has that property: $1,2,3$ have two edges to $V_1$ and $4,5,6$ has one edge. Do you mean it the other way - that vertices in $V_1$ have at most two edges to $V_2$? (Or, in the set cover instance, that all sets have size at most $2$?)

Comment: My original problem was as following: I had a list of vertices in $V_1$ having either 1 or 2 edges. I needed to find the smallest subset of vertices in $V_2$ covering all the vertices in $V_1$. In this scenario I could immediately mark all the nodes in $V_2$ pointed by vertices in $V_1$ with only 1 edge and remove all the other vertices in $V_1$ pointing to them. Then I could proceed with the greedy algorithm to mark the other vertices in $V_2$. I realize just now that my problem was way simpler than the one discussed here, and I am not even sure anymore for my case.