# A fake set covering problem?

Tags: graph-theory

I was wondering if anyone here could give me any pointers as to how to solve the following problem.

Let $B=(L,R,E)$ be an undirected bipartite graph, $ \forall u \in L$, let $S:=\{(u,w_i)\in E|w_i \in R\}$(The set of edges incident to $u$). 
The problem is to find a minimum set $K\subset L$ covering all $R$.

To clarify what I mean by covering: all vertices of $R$ should should have at least one edge connected to some $u \in K$.

My intuition is that it's not $NP-Hard$. But can not find a polynomial time algorithm. Such that:

Each vertex from $L$ could cover multi-vertices of $R$.
The vertex from $L$ which has maximum edges toward $R$ will be selected first
Each vertex of $R$ is connected with at least one vertex of $L$
Edit: Here is an example, consider the following bipartite graph: $G=\{L\cup R,E\}$, $L=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, $R=\{A,B,C,D\}$ , $E=\{1A,1B,2A,2B,2C,3A,3C,4A,4B,4D,5A,5B,6A,6D\}$

And here is a covering minimum set will be $\{2,4\}$.

I have read many algorithms and solutions like maximum matching, complete matching, stable marriage, set cover problem, vertex cover in hypergraphs ...etc. Unfortunately no one match my case.

So i am here asking your help guys cause i about to fed up!!! SOS!!

This question was poted in 
[Minimum vertices set bipartite graph covering-special case](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/839784/minimum-vertices-set-bipartite-graph-covering-special-case?noredirect=1&lq=1)

The greedy algorithm to approximate solve it is as follows:
1. Chose a vertex $a$ from $L$ which covers "more" nodes left in $R$ (i.e the vertex from $L$ with more edges)

1.1 Add the vertex $a$ the mininum cover set

1.2 Remove all the nodes in $R$ having an edge to $a$

1.3 Remove the vertex $a$ from $L$

2 In case $R$ is not empty, go to point 1

However, this is not the optimal one. Can any one help me?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/279515) to format your equations.

Comment: As stated in the answer to the question you linked to, this is exactly the same problem as the [set cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem).

Comment: It seems that you didn't use $S$ anywhere after you defined it.